# Number of anatomical entity which are able to obtain a 3D model

Tags: graphics3d, entity, anatomy

There are  $83294$ entity in anatomical data

[image]

How to find a number of anatomical entity which are able to obtain a 3D model?

for instance, I tried:

[image]

Comment: This would take a lot of computation time with how slow entities are, but I think it would be the number of entities that return `Missing[NotAvailable]` when you evaluate something like `EntityValue[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "SetOfAccessoryNerves"],EntityProperty["AnatomicalStructure", "Graphics3D"]]`, with the `EntityProperty["AnatomicalStructure", "Graphics3D"]` property

Answer (score 4):

I think that this will be slow unless WRI makes a class of “graphable” entities.

Further, many of these will never have graphs (e.g. “peripharyngeal space”).

Anyways, …

So here’s the answer I got to work:

```
(* get 20 random entities*)
RandomEntity["AnatomicalStructure", 20]

(* extract the names out of the entities *)
#[[2]] & /@ %

(* find out if any have property Graphics3DPrimities != _Missing *)
Entity["AnatomicalStructure", #]["Graphics3DPrimitives"] & /@ %
```

And here is how I derived that answer:

```
(* find all of the properties possible for this entity type *)
EntityProperties["AnatomicalStructure"]

(* eyeball the result…coming to rest on “3D graphic” and “3D graphics primitives” *)

(* use InputForm[] to understand how the Entity[] looks inside *)
(* then strip out the internal property name *)
[[2]] & /@ %

(* the corresponding names are Graphics3D and Graphics3DPrimitives *)
(* almost home…of course no journey is complete without an unfruitful detour *)
(* maybe there is a class for this entity comprising graphable entities, haha *)
EntityClassList["AnatomicalStructure"]

(* so after looking at the help (ref/AnatomyPlot3D), I tried a couple more tests *)

Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "LeftFemur"]["Graphics3DPrimitives"]
Grphics3D@%

Entity["AnatomicalStructure", “RightFemur"]["Graphics3DPrimitives"]
Grphics3D@%

Entity["AnatomicalStructure", “Stomach”][“Graphics3DPrimitives"]
Grphics3D@%

(* Finally, it becomes a relatively simply matter to get 20 items *)
RandomEntity["AnatomicalStructure", 20]

(* strip out the internal names *)
#[[2]] & /@ %

(* dump that property for each one  *)
Entity["AnatomicalStructure", #]["Graphics3DPrimitives"] & /@ %
```

HTH.